# длина кода Хэмминга для последовательности из байт

Tags: сеть

Пытаюсь разобраться как высчитать длину кода Хэмминга для последовательности из некоторого количества байт. К примеру мне нужно высчитать длину кода Хэмминга для последовательности из 31 байт. Так понимаю, что ответ - 256. Из всех примеров высчитал закономерность, что определяется примерно по формуле (число байт)*8+8, однако это не везде подходит, либо у моего преподавателя ошибки в тесте. Облазил интернет, но ничего конкретного не нашел. Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я как-то хотел записать видеоролик и выложить на Youtube из-за нехватки информации по этой теме, но пока руки так и не дошли. Для примера возьмем `1 байт = 1001 1001b`. То есть код Хэмминга = `xx1x001x1001`. Вы, вероятно, cделаете вывод, что для каждого байта получается 4 контрольных бита. НО! Теперь взглянем на `2 байта = 1001 1001 1001 1001b`. Код Хэмминга выглядит следующим образом = `xx1x001x1001100x11001`. Для 2 байт уже получается 5 контрольных бит, а не 8, замечаете? Вы же в своем примере указываете постоянно `+8.` Контрольный бит появляется на `1,2,4,8,16,32...`,  то есть сумма предыдущего числа на себя же.

Ваш ответ находится в википедии:

```
В общем случае количество контрольных бит в кодовом слове равно двоичному логарифму числа,
на единицу большего, чем количество бит кодового слова (включая контрольные биты);
логарифм округляется в большую сторону. 
Например, информационное слово длиной 1 бит требует двух контрольных разрядов,
2, 3- или 4-битовое информационное слово — трёх, 5…11-битовое — четырёх, 
12…26-битовое — пяти и т. д.
```

Comment: т.е. у меня должно получиться не 256, а 253?

Comment: @Igor, откуда вы взяли 253? Должно получиться 256. Если вам трудно работать с логарифмом, то сделайте такую последовательность: `1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256...` и переведите нужное количество байтов в биты, и потом смотрите, сколько чисел входит из этой последовательности. Например 31 байт =  248 бит, то есть = 248 + 8 = 256

Comment: Если же 15 байтов, то 15 байт =  120 бит + 7 = 127, уловили смысл?)

Comment: понял, спасибо большое